# Sending a text message through a arduino wifi shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields

I am using an Arduino uno and need to send text messages and email messages from the device based on certain events occurring.  I have the logic figured out of when to send the text message or email but don't know what shield I need to send these messages.

Comment: Do you know *how* to send them?

Comment: No I don't.  This is all new to me

Comment: Figure that part out first.

Comment: In today's world, you will realistically need an external service provider for both wifi-to-SMS gatewaying *and also simple email* as most most recipients' email services will conclude messages arriving directly from stand-alone devices are spam.  You can do small-volume SMS directly with a GSM modem if your plan allows.  But in general you should probably pick the *service* before you pick the hardware.  Do try to select something that is both secure but does not require extremely heavyweight authenticiation libraries on your embedded device.

Comment: So, with a valid connection, could I send an SMS using Twilio? It's an online software that uses python to send SMS. So technically if I had an ethernet connection using a shield, I could send a text using that program correct? *I am using an Arduino Uno by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Sending an email you need a network connection of some form.  Options include:

- Ethernet Shield
- WiFi Shield
- GSM Shield (can be expensive, but will work almost anywhere)

To send a text message you need access to a text message service. That can either be directly through a mobile phone operator or through an on-line SMS gateway service. For an on-line service the options are as above, since it's almost the same as sending an email (in fact, some gateways offer an email-to-SMS gateway option). For direct mobile provider access you can only use a GSM shield.

So really it boils down to how mobile you need it to be, and how much you are willing to spend (both on the initial hardware outlay and service provider fees and charges).

Answer (score 1):

In one of project I had seen recently, they used esp8266 for home automation and used TEMBOO.com to send SMS. I am sorry I can't help u further than this, but i am sure, Google will..

You can also refer this tutorial from adafruit on sending an sms with Temboo

https://learn.adafruit.com/sending-an-sms-with-temboo/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send `test messages` and `emails` over INTERNET using ETHERNET or WIFi you might need some REST API. There are two ways to get that part done.

1. You might create your own REST API that contains some AUTHENTICATION KEYS, USER ID, RECEIVER ID etc for emails and same for test messages.
2. You can use third part REST API that provides these functionality.

I am attaching some link you for help that will tell you how to send emails and text messages over internet.[for emails](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/sending-email-using-arduino-and-esp8266-wi-fi-module) [For Text Messages](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/sending-sms-using-esp8266)

**NOTE :-** Email api might get expired, don't get stuck over it found some other ways or third party API for that.